# Allowed memory size exhausted error

Tags: php, opencart, fatal-error

I use Opencart Script for Kitchen18.com an Ecommerce portal, this was running well till last week, but suddenly I stopped receiving orders, & when I checked myself placing a test order, In the checkout page, When I click ORDER it doesnt moves to the further page, i.e., the payment gateway page. & on the bottom of the page shows this following code hyperlinked to FB page

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/content/95/9302195/html/index.php on line 103
```

Another thing I noticed, this ERROR shows only when user LOGINED on to the site, & on every page this error is shown.

Error Log showing as `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28354561 bytes) in <b>/home/content/95/9302195/html/gemini/view/template/tool/error_log.tpl</b> on line <b>17</b><br />`

I am using Opencart 1.5.2.1 , Planning to upgrade to the 1.5.6 version with a new template but am worried to loose any data in the site.
Any help highly appreciable.
Regards
Abhishek

Comment: You have allowed memory of 64Mb (67 108 864 bytes = 65 536 kb = 64 Mb). Your script wanted to allocate additional ca 27 Mb (28 354 561 bytes = 27 690 kb = 27 Mb). The solution then could be to set the `memory_limit = 128M` - **BUT** the right solution would be to check **WHY DO YOUR INSTALLATION** require so much of memory... I guess this may have something in common with that FB extension?

Comment: How to check why my installation needs this much memory ? I am not a coder, but can install and modify/add/delete codes as guided but cannot make a new change myself. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you try to allocate more memory than a script is allowed to do.

**Solution**

1. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
   If your line shows 32M try 64M:
   memory_limit = 64M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (64MB)
2. If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an .htaccess file:

   `php_value memory_limit 128M`

   A.htaccess file is located in the public_html folder, you can modify it if it exists or create one if it does not.

Let us know if you could resolve the issue.

Comment: I have access to php.ini which is again showing in the root file, it reads as

Comment: I have access to php.ini which is again showing in the root file, it reads as(all showing in 1line, but when pasted below, it is in different lines, this as u mentioned is 64m only.

magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 18000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 12000000;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;

Comment: Try changing it to 128M

Comment: After this is done, it should work. Later try to find out what is the problem with your current installation. (A PHP script should not require so much memory for a simple shopping cart.)

Comment: Uploaded with 128M, still same issue. What might be the problem with the script ? Why is it hyperlinked to a youtube link ?